# Is there a difference between using a logical operator or a bitwise operator in an if block in Java?

Tags: java, operators, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

The contents of both of the following if blocks should be executed:

```
if( booleanFunction() || otherBooleanFunction() ) {...}
if( booleanFunction() | otherBooleanFunction() ) {...}
```

So what's the difference between using `|` or using `||`?

Note: I looked into this and found my own answer, which I included below. Please feel free to correct me or give your own view. There sure is room for improvement!

Comment: I don't get the point of this question, you ask a question which you answer yourself - before anyone else can answer?

Comment: @Nim and Durandal: Hmm.. I might have missed the point, but according to [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) it is actually fine to answer your own questions if you think it might be relevant to others. I solved my own question and thought I'd share, so I went to the trouble of documenting it here. Didn't mean to offend anyone

Comment: @Miquel, it's not about offence, IMO it's the fact that you answered the question immediately which presents the appearance that you are attempting to farm reputation to cynics (such as myself! :)), spare a little time next time, to see what the community produces, and if you find no suitable answer, contribute - then it removes any such appearance...

Comment: @Nim allright, point taken. Clearly this has been misinterpreted, so I'll do as you suggest in the future, and in the meantime, I'll move the discussion to meta. Perhaps we shouldn't have "Answer your own question" directly under the box to *post* the question.

Comment: I don't see what the big deal is. Maybe Miquel didn't have all day to wait around to finish what he was trying to accomplish. If I was in that situation and already had a sufficient solution to my question, I wouldn't wait around just for appearances.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The logical operator works on booleans, and the bitwise operator works on bits. In this case, the effect is going to be the same, but there are two differences:

1. The bitwise operator is not meant for that, which makes it harder to read but most importantly
2. The logical OR operator will evaluate the first condition. If it's true, it does not matter what the next condition results in, the result will be true, so *the second clause is not executed*

Here's some handy code to prove this:

```
public class OperatorTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Logical Operator:");
        if(sayAndReturn(true, "first") || sayAndReturn(true, "second")){
            //doNothing
        }

        System.out.println("Bitwise Operator:");
        if(sayAndReturn(true, "first") | sayAndReturn(true, "second")){
            //doNothing
        }
    }

    public static boolean sayAndReturn(boolean ret, String msg){
        System.out.println(msg);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: So is there a practical usage for the & operator in an if statement?

Comment: The only point in using it would be to have both clauses executed as a side effect, and I'd consider that a really bad idea, since you probably shouldn't be relying on side effects in an if in the first place, and it's very easy to missread

Answer (score 41):

The two have different uses. Although in many cases (when dealing with booleans) it may appear that they have the same effect, it is important to note that the logical-OR is short circuit, meaning that if its first argument evaluates to true, then the second argument is left unevaluated. The bitwise operator evaluates both of its arguments regardless.

Similarly, the logical-AND is short-circuit, meaning that if its first argument evaluates to false, then the second is left unevaluated. Again, the bitwise-AND is not.

You can see this in action here:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 1;
System.out.println(x+y == 1 || y/x == 1);
System.out.println(x+y == 1 |  y/x == 1);
```

The first print statement works just fine and returns true since the first argument evaluates to true, and hence evaluation stops. The second print statement errors since it is not short circuit, and a division by zero is encountered.

Answer (score 7):

for programmers, there is only one difference.

1. your logical operators are logical ones,i.e. they test only one condition and get result based on that.

**booleanFunction() || otherBooleanFunction()** will be true if either  is true. likewise, **booleanFunction() && otherBooleanFunction()** will be false if either is false. So, why test the other one. that's what logical operators do.

But bitwise ones check both. A frequent application of this concept is as follows.

```
if(someObject != null && someObject.somemethod())
```

So, in this case if you replace `&&` by `&` then wait for a disaster. You will get nasty NullPointerException soon...

Answer (score 4):

```
if( booleanFunction() || otherBooleanFunction() ) {...}
```

In this condition if `booleanFunction()` returns `true` then `otherBooleanFunction()` would not be executed.

```
if( booleanFunction() | otherBooleanFunction() ) {...}
```

But in bitwise operator both functions - `booleanFunction()` and `otherBooleanFunction()` would be executed no matter `booleanFunction()` returns `true` or `false`

Answer (score 0):

Difference between bitwise a d logical operator-
1. Bitwise operator works on bit whereas logical operator works on statement.
2. Bitwise  and is represented by & whereas logical and is represented by &&.
3. Bitwise  or is represented by | whereas logical or is represented by ||.