# Logical OR operator bug - | vs | |

Tags: java

I have a question about an existing code written by somebody else which I feel is buggy. Need your advice ,

```
if (encounter.getProvider() == null | encounter.getProvider().getIdentity() == null) {
            errorMessages.add("Provider information is incomplete");
        }
```

encounter.getProvider() is an Employee kind of Object and is allowed to be null inside Encounter. I found issue while writing unit tests and original developer doesn't work here anymore.

Issue is even if `encounter.getProvider() == null` is true then second condition is evaluated and throws a NPE so I believe that operator should be changed to logical OR ( | | ) so that if `encounter.getProvider() == null` is true then second condition (`encounter.getProvider().getIdentity() == null`) is not evaluated and NPE is avoided.
**Am I correct?**
 **or original developer might have something else in mind for using single pipe logical OR?**

```
encounter.getProvider().getIdentity()
```

returns object of type - `Identity`. I tested code with logical OR operator ( | | ) and I don't get NPE if first operand is `true`.

Please suggest.

Comment: This looks like a bug. You are correct

Comment: Thanks, logged a bug.

Comment: You are mistaken in the wording of your question. The `|` operator, as used here, **is** a logical OR operator. So is `||`, but the double version doesn't evaluate the right if the left is true. The `|` operator is *also* a bit-wise operator, when the operands are numbers. See JLS: "[Boolean Logical Operators &, ^, and |](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2)" and "[Conditional-Or Operator ||](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24)".

Comment: Thanks, I edited title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`logical-OR is short circuit`, meaning that if its `first argument evaluates to true, then the second argument is left unevaluated`.

The `bitwise operator` evaluates both of its arguments regardless.

So it is buggy code, please change to add `||`

A good read [Is there a difference between using a logical operator or a bitwise operator in an if block in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156522/is-there-a-difference-between-using-a-logical-operator-or-a-bitwise-operator-in)

Comment: Thanks, I logged a bug.

Comment: Clarification: The `|` operator, as used here, is a "[Boolean Logical Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2)", not an "[Integer Bitwise Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1)", and the `||` is called a "[Conditional-Or Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24)", according to the Java Language Specification (linked).

Answer (score 1):

Single OR - | will evaluate the next expression regardless of the result of the current one, while double OR - || will terminate when true condition is met.

In your case only if the `encounter.getProvider()` is not `null` second condition will be evaluated and `NPE` will no get thrown, so you are right, it's a bug.